# Swift. Condionally segue from tableview in split view master to different viewcontrollers dependent on document type

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, uisplitviewcontroller, uistoryboardsegue

I have a tableViewController as the master of a splitViewController. In the tableView i want to display a list of different types of files such as pdfs, images, word docs, csv etc (similar to Dropbox app for example). I've created an imageViewController to display image files and connected this as the detail of the splitViewController. I'm now starting work on creating a PDFViewController where i want to implement PDFKit to view PDF files. What are my options on segueing to different viewControllers when a user taps on a particular file type in the tableView *when that tableView is the master of a splitViewController*. I tried setting numerous viewControllers as the detail viewController of the splitViewController and then conditionally segue in code with shouldPerformSegue etc but it seems to only allow one to be selected.

Comment: How about calling `performSegueWithIdentifier` from `didSelect` based on whatever you are using to identify whether a cell is pointing to an image, pdf, etc?